# Difference between those 2 Pandas code that drop entries = 0 and rename a column

Tags: python, pandas

I am following the University MOOC "Introduction to Data Science" and in a question, I don't understand the difference and the answer although my way of solving the problem is very similar and **both works**.

This is the problem:

> Suppose we are working on a DataFrame that holds information on our equipment for an upcoming backpacking trip.
>
> Can you use method chaining to modify the DataFrame df in one statement to drop any entries where 'Quantity' is 0 and rename the column 'Weight' to 'Weight (oz.)'?

This is what I do :

```
print((df.where(df['Quantity'] != 0)
         .dropna()
         .rename(columns={'Weight':'Weigth (oz.)'})))
```

This is the answer :

```
print((df.drop(df[df['Quantity'] == 0]
         .index)
         .rename(columns={'Weight': 'Weight (oz.)'})))
```

I don't understand in the correction why it is needed to put `.index`
and how adding it remove the Quantity == 0.
I used `df.drop(df[df['Quantity'] == 0]` to see what happend and saw that the program crashed, but I would like to have more explanations.

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df[df['Quantity'] == 0]` returns all the rows which suffices the condition: `df['Quantity'] == 0`. Calling `index` on it gives you indexes which suffices the condition.

The docs for [`df.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) says:

> labels : single label or list-like
>   Index or column labels to drop.

This means when we pass `df[df['Quantity'] == 0].index` , we are asking the `drop` func to drop the list of indexes to drop , also since we don't define the `axis` it is presumed to be a row index.